# Fixing Time Machine Backup Broken by Deleting Most Recent Backup with tmutil

Tags: time-machine

I broke my Time Machine backup by using `tmutil delete` on the most recent backup.  This meant that the "Latest" symlink no longer pointed to a valid location.  My attempts to create a replacement symlink have failed, probably due to some sort ACL issue or a problem with extended attributes.

Here is an attempt to recreate the symbolic link:

```
DeepThought:DeepThought cclark$ sudo ln -sn ./2020-12-20-161820 Latest
Password:
ln: Latest: Operation not permitted
```

Has anyone ever recovered from this situation?

I have tried disabling SIP, and have made sure that Terminal has been granted Full Disk access.  I have also tried creating an alias using Finder, which was successful but was not recognized by Time Machine.

The backup is on a Synology NAS.

Comment: Can you not just do another backup? I would assume that should fix the symlink.

Answer (score 1):

The problem eventually worked itself out.  I think that choosing to verify the backup may have helped.

Comment: This is a case where it’s hard to pin down cause and effect from correlation. Glad that with patience it fixed itself